# memory structure of two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm learning c++ and i am not good at english so you may not understand what i wrote...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int v[2][2] = {0,};
   cout << v << endl;
   cout << endl;
   cout << v[0] << endl;
   cout << endl;
   cout << &v[0][0] << endl;
   cout << sizeof(&v) << " " << sizeof(&v[0]) << " " << sizeof(&v[0][0]) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and the result is..

0x61ff00

0x61ff00

0x61ff00

4 4 4

the name of array(above code, v) is a pointer to the address of the memory block that contains the value of the first element of array v. and &v[0][0], v[0] is all same.(because v = &v[0])
my question is,
v is a pointer to the address of the first element of array v and its size is 4 byte.
&v is the address of the first element of array v and its size is 4 byte.
&v[0] is the address of first row of the array v and its size is 4 byte.
&v[0][0] is the address of the first row, first column element of array v and its size is 4 byte.
the address of v, v[0], v[0][0] is all same.
then, what is the memory structure of two-dimensional array? the same address has 3 different values.

thanks for reading and I'm sorry that the writing is not smooth.

Comment: `the address of v, v[0], v[0][0] is all same.`No its not. You're printing the sizes of `&v`, `&v[0]` and `&v[0][0]`, not `v`, `v[0]` and `v[0][0]`.

Comment: `v` is not a pointer -- it's an array.  The compiler will convert it to a pointer when you use it for pointer-like things (such as passing it to something expects a pointer, or explicitly taking its address).  The same goes for `v[0]` which is also an array.

Comment: If an `int` has a minimum legal size of 2 bytes, how can an array of 4 `int`s possibly have a size of 4?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While `v` and `v[0]` and `v[0][0]` all have the same address they do have different types. For example v is an array while v[0][0] is an integer. Their addresses result in pointers to different types.

This is no different than

```
struct A {
    int x;
};

A a;

// &a is the same as &a.x
```

The language guarantees that in arrays and simple structs the first element is at offset 0 so they have the same address.

In your code you do this:

```
   cout << sizeof(&v) << " " << sizeof(&v[0]) << " " << sizeof(&v[0][0]) << endl;
```

What you are printing here are the sizes of pointers to the array or elements in the array. On your system pointers have a size of 4 so that is what you get.

Now lets turn this example into modern C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   array<array<int, 2>, 2> v = {{{0}}};
   cout << &v << endl;
   cout << &v[0] << endl;
   cout << &v[0][0] << endl;
   cout << "Size of addresses: " << sizeof(&v) << " " << sizeof(&v[0]) << " " << sizeof(&v[0][0]) << endl;
   cout << "Size of values   : " << sizeof(v) << " " << sizeof(v[0]) << " " << sizeof(v[0][0]) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Program returned: 0
0x7ffe86e116c0
0x7ffe86e116c0
0x7ffe86e116c0
Size of addresses: 8 8 8
Size of values   : 16 8 4
```

On godbolt.org the size of a pointer is 8 so that is what you get for all 3 addresses. But the size of the array, subarray and single element show what you expect it to be.